# Adding "this.disabled" to onclick to stop duplicate form submissions

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have found a good short solution to prevent multiple form submissions but struggling with the correct syntax to incorporate them both together.

My code is

```
    <div class="select_wrapper" style="margin-top:25px">
    <div onclick="change_page('data');" id="get-results">
        Results
    </div>
```

This is the button disable code from here
http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/disable-submit-button-in-html-javascript-avoid-multiple-form-submission.html

```
  <form action="submit.jsp" method="post" >
  <input type="submit" name="SUBMIT" value="Submit Form"  onclick="this.disabled='disabled'" />
  </form>
```

I have tried

```
onclick="change_page('data')"this.disabled='disabled';
```

with no joy. Any other ideas?

Comment: `onclick="change_page('data')"this.disabled='disabled';` <--- quotes are messed up `onclick="change_page('data'); this.disabled='disabled';"` but problem with disbaling an item onclick is it will cancel the form submission.

Answer (score 0):

The onclick attribute fires on a mouse click on the element.

You can call multiple statements in the `onclick=""` attribute separated by semicolon or in a more cleaner you can call a JavaScript function:

Html:

```
<div onclick="myFunction(this, 'data')" id="get-results">
    Results
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction(elem, data) {
    // Call other function
    change_page(data);

    // Set element attribute disabled
    elem.disabled = 'disabled';
}
```